# GitLab Free version vs Premium (self-managed)

Tags: gitlab, version, difference, enterprise, price

I would like to understand if, at an enterprise level, it makes sense to use the free version of GitLab or the premium version.

GitLab would only be used as a code repository.

Looking on the official website, on the pricing page https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/, storage limits are indicated for the free version (5GB), but by installing the Self-managed version of the product, I would really have storage limitations storage or limitations on the number of users per namespace?

Answer (score 2):

I have use the free version for years, using an on-premise installation of GitLab. No limitation (beside what the system imposes in term of disk space/memory).

The main limitation is in feature, when you want advanced CI/CD features which are not available in the free version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I thought so but wasn't sure.